# How to find all differentiable functions $f: \mathbb {R} \rightarrow \mathbb {R}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, real-numbers

Find all differentiable functions $f: \mathbb {R} \rightarrow \mathbb {R}$, that satisfy the condition $f'(x) = -5f(x) \not= 0$, where $x \in \mathbb {R}$.

I tried to find a differential from $f'(x)$, and continue from there, but it didn't get me anywhere.

Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: Consider the function $g(x) = e^{5x} f(x)$ and look at its derivative

Comment: So you want to solve $y'+5y=0$. Do you know how to solve these equations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve $\frac{dy}{dx}=-5y,$ giving you

$$\int \frac{dy}{y}=\int(-5)\,dx$$
solving this gives you $$\ln(y)=-5x+C$$
since $e^{\ln(y)}=y$ we have 
$$y=e^{-5x+C}=e^C(e^{-5x}).$$

You need to account for the fact that the coefficient of your solution may be negative. Put $e^C=A,$ and 
$$y=\pm A(e^{-5x}).$$

Answer (score 4):

This is a separable equation, rewrite as 
$$
\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=-5\implies\int\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\mathrm dx=-5\int\mathrm dx\implies \log(|f(x)|)=-5x+C\implies f(x)=\pm Ae^{-5x}
$$
(Note how we used $f(x)\ne 0$).

Comment: same remark, where are the negative solutions?

Comment: @zwim fair point, i have added in the requisite absolute values

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Judiciously integrate the equation and see that all differentiable functions $f: \mathbb {R} \rightarrow \mathbb {R}$, that satisfy the condition $f'(x) = -5f(x) \not= 0$, where $x \in \mathbb {R}$ differs at most by some constant.